# Insertion Sort on a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
class topList():
    __slots__ = ( "name", "gender", "occurences" )
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'topList({s.name!r}, {s.gender!r}, {s.occurences!r})'.format(s=self)
    def __str__(self):
        return 'topList({s.name}, {s.gender}, {s.occurences})'.format(s=self)

def mkList( name, gender, occurences ):
    find = topList()
    find.name = name
    find.gender = gender
    find.occurences = occurences
    return find

def insertionSort( data ):
    """insertionSort: list( Orderable ) -> list( Orderable )
       Sort the contents of the data list in place.
       Note: unlike the course notes, swapping is not used here.
            A temp variable is used instead.
    """
    mark = 1 # Location of first unordered element
    dataLen = len( data )
    while mark < dataLen:
        temp = data[ mark ]
        i = mark - 1 # i points to the value in data we're comparing to temp
        while i >= 0 and temp < data[ i ]:
            data[ i + 1 ] = data[ i ]
            i -= 1
        data[ i + 1 ] = temp
        mark += 1

def main():
    year = input( 'Enter year: ' )
    file = open( 'yob' + year + '.txt' )
    lst = []
    lst1 = []
    femaleLst = []
    maleLst = []
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip().split( "," )
        names = mkList( line[0], line[1], line[2] )
        lst.append( names )
        if names.gender == 'F':
            femaleLst += [ line ]
        else:
            maleLst += [ line ]
    while len( lst1 ) < 20:
        male = maleLst.pop(0)
        female = femaleLst.pop(0)
        if maleLst[ 2 ] > femaleLst[ 2 ]:
            lst1 += [ male ]
        else:
            lst1 += [ female ]
    insertionSort( lst1[ int(names.occurences) ] )
    index = 0
    for element in lst1:
        index = index + 1
        print( index, ", ".join( element ) )
main()
```

it gives me back this result:
Enter year: 1999

```
1 Emily, F, 26535
2 Hannah, F, 21666
3 Matthew, M, 30412
4 Sarah, F, 19079
5 Samantha, F, 19032
6 18130, Ashley, F
7 Andrew, M, 23846
8 Joseph, M, 23198
9 Daniel, M, 22663
10 Elizabeth, F, 15327
11 Brandon, M, 21597
12 Lauren, F, 13912
13 Kayla, F, 13288
14 William, M, 20704
15 John, M, 20335
16 Victoria, F, 11864
17 Emma, F, 11719
18 Abigail, F, 11677
19 James, M, 18549
20 Olivia, F, 11252
```

I do not understand why the insertion sort function is not sorting the number of times the name occurs. Please help.

Comment: What's wrong with number 6? Is the source text file incorrectly formatted?

Comment: Why do you need `while len( lst1 ) < 20` loop?

Answer (score 0):

You want it to sort on occurrences.
In the line,  `while i >= 0 and temp < data[ i ]:` temp and data[i] are instances of topList.
Try  `while i >= 0 and temp.occurrences < data[ i ]occurrences:`.